# Easy word riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> I fly without wings,
>   I cry without eyes.
>   In me you can store things,
>   of almost unlimited size.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you...

> A cloud

Because:

- > Clouds don't need wings to fly in the sky
- > Clouds rain without needing any eyes
- > Cloud servers/services allows storage of large files on the internet

I had originally given the following for the last point, but revised it based on *athin*'s comments and OP's confirmation...

- > Large things like airplanes are easily hidden inside a cloud, mountains can be cloaked by clouds

Answer (score 3):

The word is

> zip

Can fly without wings

> Another way to tell someone to "zip up" is "your fly is open"

Can cry without eyes

> The wannacry virus works operates with archives or "zip" files

Can store things of unlimited size

> A zip file can store files of unlimited size (given the hardware space)

Comment: haha very creative. This one is great :))

Answer (score 1):

Sort of similar to Phylyps, but it was the first thing that came to my mind.

> Water

Because

- > Water flies when it evaporates in to the atmosphere
- > Water cries down to earth when it rains
- > Most of our planet it stored in water, plus anything you put in water just sort of pushes the water to surround it